# I need some pointers about threading in my program

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to create an app which scans ports of given IP address individually like so:

```
private void ScanPort(IPAddress address, int port)
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        IAsyncResult result = client.BeginConnect(address, port, null, null);

        if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, false)) txtDisplay.AppendText("Port: " + nudFrom.Value.ToString() + " is open." + Environment.NewLine);
        else txtDisplay.AppendText("Port: " + nudFrom.Value.ToString() + " is closed." + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Now, scanning IP with this code takes some time, especially if i have 100+ ports to scan.

I though of looking into threading. The problem is that I'm kind of blank about how to work with threads but I did read some articles from MSDN or other articles which show how to do basic threading.

Now, I'm not sure how to implement threading in my program. I could create an event handler pointing to my ScanPort method but then if I initialize 1 or more threads it would start pinging from the beginning of the port. The other though I had was how many threads should I start.

Do you get the idea? I need some basic ideas of how to implement threading into my program.

Comment: I would suggest that you *don't* need threads for this, you just need to use asynchronous I/O. There should be absolutely no problem for a single thread to scan 100 ports very quickly.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, it's pretty quick to check when ports are open, but when are closed I have to wait for timeout before I can check another. Besides, don't I use asynchronous scan?

Comment: Yes, you are using asynchronous I/O, but you're using it in a synchronous manner. You're starting a connection, then waiting for something to happen. What I'm suggesting is that you could call `BeginConnect` for multiple *different* connections all at the same time.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, well, then I might have to double check the code to make it asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways in which a single threaded program can become multi-threaded in .Net.  If you are interested in learning the mechanics of threading in .Net, then this might be a good opportunity, however as others have suggested looking for uses of multi-threading in and of itself is not exactly a worthwhile activity.  Programming is hard enough without throwing parallelism and/or concurrency into the mix.

If you want to look into multi-threading in .Net, you need to read about:

[System.Threading.Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

[System.Threading.Threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)

[Other methods...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx)